# In gnome-boxes, how do you increase the box size?

Tags: gnome

The panel of my computer has a resolution of 3840 x 2160 pixels. If I open a gnome-boxes session, the code of the virtual machine occupies a space little bigger than a postage stamp. GNOME-Boxes reports that I'm seeing 1920 x 1080 pixels. The following picture shows the gnome-blocks desktop.

[Full-screen view of GNOME Boxes with one virtual machine showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2yZl.jpg)

Does anyone know how to increase the size of the displayed box?

Answer (score 1):

I've just been searching for the same answer and came across your question. I've just solved this for me, so hope this helps you.

To enable the change in 'box size', display resolution and more functionality, install Spice onto the Host OS and into the Guest OS.

See here for the files to download depending on the which OSes you're using:
https://www.spice-space.org/download.html

From that page you can find more help and tutorials as well as explanations as to the additional functionality this will provide.Also, now you know spice-vdagent etc is what you will need, google searches become more helpful too.